# What is correct syntax for limits of x-axis and y-axis when using fplot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

INPUT

```
disp('Solution Domain Range Input')
prompt='lims='; lims=input(prompt);
disp(' ')
```

OUTPUT
Solution Domain Range Input

```
lims=[-3 3 ] works fine, x axis range is from -3 to 3
```

also tried

```
lims=[-3 3 -3 3 ] gives error message
```

...

INPUT

```
odes = diff(Y)== A*Y + B
[xSol(t), ySol(t)] = dsolve(odes);
xSolvpa = vpa(xSol)
ySolvpa = vpa(ySol)
fplot(xSolvpa, lims)
hold on
fplot(ySolvpa,lims)
```

ERROR MSG

```
Error using fplot (line 145)
Invalid parameter '-3  3 -...'.
```

How to do?
MM

Comment: The limits parameter in `fplot` is only applicable to the x-axis, which makes sense since it only is designed to plot one-dimensional functions.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The range of both the x and y-axes makes a big difference in plotting solutions to differential equations. I am plotting xSol and ySol vs t.  Fplot selects t values to plot whereas plot uses t values specified by the user.  I was having trouble with plot syntax and found fplot syntax to work better. I am trying to reproduce solutions to problems seen in textbooks. It is a good way to learn.

Comment: I found the axis statement. It works very well with fplot.

Comment: The code you wrote makes it unclear where your intention is simply to restrict the viewing window of the plot.

Comment: The lims statement includes limits for both x and y-axes [xmin xmax ymin ymax]. Using the axis statement adjusts the ranges of the x and y-axes. Not all syntax for graphs I find online work.  fplot chooses the x values wisely to show oscillations which are not seen with user-specified domain points sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!

```
lims=[-1.1 1.5 -1 3]    
fplot(xSolvpa)
axis(lims)
```